# Error on Journey Builder validation Custom Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, json, heroku, custom-activity

I have a Custom Activity, it's mean to trigger Whatsapp messages through an API.
For some cases, the activity works correctly, but sometimes, on the validation step, it returns me the error: "The rest activity REST-1 contains an invalid argument undefined. Reconfigure the activity". Heroku hosts the app, in case this info is required.

This is my config.json file

```json
{
    "workflowApiVersion": "1.1",
    "metaData": {
      "category": "message",
      "isConfigured": true
    },
    "type": "REST",
    "lang": {
      "en-US": {
        "name": "name",
        "step1Label": "Activity"
      }
    },
    "arguments": {
      "execute": {
        "url": "https://url.com/api/data",
        "verb": "POST",
        "format": "json",
        "inArguments": []
      }
    },
    "configurationArguments": {
      "applicationExtensionKey": "111111111111111111111111111111",
      "save": {
        "url": "https://url.com/api/save",
        "verb": "POST",
        "useJwt": true
      },
      "publish": {
        "url": "https://url.com/api/publish",
        "verb": "POST",
        "useJwt": true
      },
      "stop": {
        "url": "https://url.com/api/stop",
        "verb": "POST",
        "useJwt": true
      },
      "validate": {
        "url": "https://url.com/api/validate",
        "verb": "POST",
        "useJwt": true
      }
    },
    "wizardSteps": [{ "label": "Configure Activity", "key": "step1" }],
    "userInterfaces": {
      "configModal": {
        "height": 400,
        "width": 1000,
        "fullscreen": false
      }
    },
    "schema": {
      "arguments": {
        "execute": {
          "inArguments": [],
          "outArguments": []
        }
      }
    }
  }
```